# OpenCL Matrix Average calculation optimizing?

Tags: memory-management, matrix, opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to calculate the average of a webcam stream in python using pyopenCL. As a test I am trying to calculate the average of a representative matrix over a number of frames, as can be seen below:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
import time
import os

os.environ['PYOPENCL_CTX']='0' 

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
length = 480
width = 320
nFrames = 60

matrix = np.zeros(shape=(length,width,nFrames)).astype(np.float32)
for i in range(nFrames):
  matrix[:,:,i] = float(i)

matrix_GPU = np.zeros(shape=(length,width)).astype(np.float32)
matrix_CPU = np.zeros_like(matrix_GPU)
final_matrix = np.zeros_like(matrix2t)

matrix_GPU_vector = np.reshape(matrix_GPU,matrix_GPU.size)



mf = cl.mem_flags
dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, matrix_GPU.nbytes)


prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void summatrices(const unsigned int size, 
                  __global float * a, 
                  __global float * b, 
                  __global float * sum) 
    {
    int i = get_global_id(0); 
    sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    """).build()


t0 =  time.time() 
for i in range(nFrames):
    matrix_GPU = matrix[:,:,i].astype(np.float32)
    matrix_GPU_vector = np.reshape(matrix_GPU,matrix_GPU.size)
    a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=matrix_GPU_vector)
    b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=final_matrix)
    prg.summatrices(queue, matrix_GPU_vector.shape, None,np.int32(len(matrix_GPU_vector)), a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)
    temp_matrix = np.empty_like(matrix_GPU_vector)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, temp_matrix , dest_buf)
    final_matrix = temp_matrix

final_matrix = final_matrix/nFrames
final_matrix = np.reshape(final_matrix,(length,width))
delta_t =  time.time()  - t0


print 'OpenCL GPU Multiplication: ' + str(delta_t)
matrix_CPU = np.sum(matrix[:,:,:], axis=2)/nFrames
delta_t =  time.time()  - (t0 + delta_t)

print 'OpenCL CPU Multiplication: ' + str(delta_t)
#print matrix
#print final_matrix
#print matrix_CPU

eq = (final_matrix==matrix_CPU).all()
print eq
```

It appears, however, that my code is a factor 30 slower on my GPU than it is on my CPU. This is most likely due to my use of the for-loop and my lack of workgroup allocation.

Is it possible to strip out the python for-loop and allocate my workgroups properly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it is a test I guess that at the end of the day you want to do much more computation than some add. Here are 2 things you can try to enhance your code:

1. Do not create each time the a_buf and b_buf. Creation of buffers is costly. Create them   outside of the loop and then in the loop use the `cl.enqueue_write_buffer()` function or the  `cl.enqueue_copy()`. It seems that the first function is now deprecate and replace by the  second one. So it should be something like `cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_buf, matrix_GPU_vector)`
2. I guess it doesn't cost much but do not reshape the matrix `matrix_GPU` it's already aligned properly in memory.

BTW if you making a test to simulate a app that receives a stream from a webcam, shouldn't you use RGB matrix? I mean that you could receive 24bit RGB image wich could be simulated better with int8, no?

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I do want to make it quite a bit more costly than it currently is, as the plan is to use a mixture of Gaussians to estimate the background of the video. Seeing as the average, or standard deviation, of integers doesn't need to be an integer itself, I am using floats. Also, if I use anything other than float32, my code has a tendency to give gibberish results (I guess something to do with data allocation).

Thank you for both the tips! I will definitely try them out to see if I can get some speedup!

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that you will do more advanced things later:

I would work in non-blocking mode and create 4 buffers, a1/a2, b1/b2 (create only once at the beggining). 
Also 2 queues, one for I/O and one for kernels.
Then each odd frame copy data to a1 and b1 using the I/O_queue, and run the kernel using the kernel_queue. Each even frame use the a2/b2:

```
IO->a1-| a2-| a1-| 
IO->b1-| b2-| b1-| 
KER->  ke-| ke-| ke-|
IO->      re   re   re
```

You should use events a to check that the kernels are not launched before the data has been copied (using the return values of buffer.enqueue_copy()). Or the kernel 2 runs only after kernel 1, etc...

Since OpenCL allows to add a batch of operations, you can add everything in the for loop, then wait only till the last kernel has finished.

It is tricky, but it will give you the maximum possible speed if you follow that system.